# IE 11 title not working when page zoomed

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

So as part of a project, I have some bars on a graph defined like so

```
<area shape=\"rect\" coords=\"{0},{1},{2},{3}\" alt=\"{4}" title="{4}\">
```

where the coordinates, alt, and title are injected by the backend service. This works just fine on all browsers, except for IE 11 on Windows 7 where the tooltip won't pop up if you're zoomed in past about 110%. Unfortunately, the only solution I've been able to find so far is to go back to 100% zoom, which is great except this is customer facing (which is why we're supporting IE 11 in the first place) so we're concerned they might not even realize it's not working and just assume the information isn't there.

Has anyone found another workaround to get the title, or any other tooltip for that matter, to work on IE 11 while zoomed in?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this, but it may be a bug specific to the IE11's Area element - try wrapping the <area /> element in a legacy element like a <div> or <span> and placing the title there. Otherwise, you could use an actual HTML element to display the title.

Comment: Unfortunately, the area is in a map so I can't wrap it in another element. It looks like what's happening is the underlying image is being zoomed, but the area coordinates aren't being updated. Once you zoom in too far, they no longer line up and the area titles no longer trigger when you mouse over the bar.